# Translate Screen points to Picture Points

Tags: c#, image, winforms

I am trying to draw text on image using `System.Drawing.Graphics` but I'm having a little difficulty in positioning the text correctly in the image. My program is supposed to allow the user to draw a textbox, edit it and then apply it's text permanently to an image in the `PictureBox`. But each time I try to draw the text to the image, it is either too small, or positioned in the wrong spot. Here's my code:

```
var bmp = new Bitmap(OriginalImage);

// Box is the already drawn textbox.
using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
{
    graphics.DrawString(Box.Text,new Font(Box.Font.FontFamily, Box.Font.Size, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, Box.Location);  
}
```

Also, the `PictureBox` `SizeMode` is set to `Zoom`, though the textbox is always well positioned (made sure of that :)). Any ideas or suggestions would be cherished, thanks in advance.

Comment: @L. Guthardt Exactly :(. Do you have any ideas on what I could do?

Comment: @Prince Owen  Keep a copy of that image. Don't work on the image you are showing (in the PictureBox). When you have to modify it, create a new bitmap, draw on it, and then pass it to .Image property of you PictureBox. Think of it as the "BackGround Layer".